# xml reader opens the file but still gives the 'Load Data before trying to read' error

Tags: php, xmlreader

I have this weird error I don't really know how is this possible. The xmlreader reads the file, but when i am trying to iterate it, it still gives me the error "Message: XMLReader::read(): Load Data before trying to read".

Here is my code:

```
$what = 'title';
    $reader = new XMLReader;

    if (!$reader->open(base_url().'resources/thexml.xml'))
    {
        die("Failed to open");
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'success!';
    }


    while($reader->read())
    {
        if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'item')
        {
            $exp = $reader->expand();
            if ($exp->nodeName == $what)
                echo "<b>" . $exp->nodeName . " : </b>" . $exp->nodeValue . "<br />";

        }

        $reader->close();
    }
```

And this is the output:

**success!**
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: XMLReader::read(): Load Data before trying to read

Filename: controllers/welcome.php

Line Number: **102**

The success shows it reads the file but still gives me the error that I need to open first. Line number 102 is "while($reader->read())" line. Please help

Comment: Looks like the xml is invalid. Can you prove that using an xml validator? (For example: http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: it seems that it is invalid. the link gives me "Sorry! This document cannot be checked." The xml file is actually this link http://grid.mk/rss/kultura I just did right click save as. Why would it be invalid?

Comment: looks ok on the first view. let me check that

Comment: I changed the encoding to utf-8 now is ok "This document was Tentatively checked as XML" with green color. Maybe i have some problem with the encoding in my code also?

Comment: Probably... It's hard to find out whats going wrong here. I'm still investigating

Comment: What about to use `DOMDocument` ? Would this being an alternative for you?

Comment: well i don't know, I'm just trying to add news into my website (which is a project for school) from that link, but somehow, nothing seems to work :( If that is a solution than why not! I will need to learn what that is and how to use it though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem: You need to move the `$reader->close();` statement outside of the loop. Otherwise the xml document gets closed after the first loop and the subsequent read operations fails.

The read loop should look like this:

```
while($reader->read())
{
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'item')
    {
        $exp = $reader->expand();
        if ($exp->nodeName == $what)
            echo "<b>" . $exp->nodeName . " : </b>" . $exp->nodeValue . "<br />";

    }
}

// Close the document after(!) the loop
$reader->close();
```

Having this your code works properly.

---

However, using `XMLReader` doesn't seem the appropriate solution here. This because it requires to loop over all(!) tags in the input xml while you are only interested in the `<item>` nodes. I would use `DOMDocument` together with `XPath` here:

```
// Create an load the DOM document
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('thexml.xml');

// Create an XPath selector
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

// Get all <title> nodes inside <item> nodes
foreach($selector->query('//item/title') as $item) {
    echo '<b>Title: ' . $item->nodeValue . '</br>';
}
```

Comment: ah man, that's just brilliant, i got a manly tear xD how do i award you or smth? :)

Comment: You are welcome! Yeah it was hard to find, firstly I was completely on the wrong track :) ...